# Reading from file using read() function

Tags: c, file

I have to write a program that reads numbers in separate lines each. Is it possible to read only one line of the file and then read an `int` from the buffer, and so on until the end of file? It is really hard to find good examples of using read and write.  My example is kind of working but I'd like to read until it detects `'\n'` char and then convert buffer into int.

```
#include <fcntl.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <iostream>

int fd[2];

void readFile(int fd) {
    unsigned char buffer[10];
    int bytes_read;
    int k=0;
    do {
        bytes_read = read(fd, buffer, 10); 
        k++;
            for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            printf("%c", buffer[i]);
        }
    }
    while (bytes_read != 0); 
}

int tab[50];

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if(argv[1] == NULL || argv[2] == NULL)   {
            printf("Function requires two arguments!\nGood bye...\n");
            return -1;
    }
    else {
        if (access(argv[1], F_OK) == 0) {
            fd[0] = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
        }
        else { 
            fd[0] = open(argv[1], O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_SYNC, 0700);
            const int size = 50;
                for(int i=0; i<size; i++) {
                    char buf[10];   
                    sprintf(buf, "%d\n", i+1);
                    write(fd[0], buf, strlen(buf));
                }
                close(fd[0]);
            fd[0] = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
            if (access(argv[2], F_OK) == 0) 
                fd[1] = open(argv[2], O_WRONLY);
            else 
                fd[1] = open(argv[2], O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, 0700);
        }
    }

    if (access(argv[2], F_OK) == 0) 
        fd[1] = open(argv[2], O_WRONLY); 
    else 
        fd[1] = open(argv[2], O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, 0700);


    readFile(fd[0]);
    close(fd[0]);
    close(fd[1]);
}
```

Revised code:

```
void readFile(int fd) {
    char buffer[10];
    int bytes_read;
    int k = 0;
    do {
        char t = 0;
        bytes_read = read(fd, &t, 1); 
        buffer[k++] = t;    
        printf("%c", t);
        if(t == '\n' && t == '\0') {
            printf("%d", atoi(buffer));
            for(int i=0; i<10; i++) 
                buffer[i]='\0';
            k = 0;
        }
    }
    while (bytes_read != 0); 
}
```

Comment: And the question is ?

Comment: Ohh sry. How to read only one line

Comment: If `read` has an error and returns `-1`, your while loop will never terminate.  Always expect errors.

Comment: Rather than `do { ... read() ...`, consider `while ((bytes_read = read(fd, &t, 1)) > 0) {`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Read Byte by Byte and check that each byte against `'\n'` if it is not,  then store it into `buffer`
if it is `'\n'` add `'\0'` to buffer and then use `atoi()`

You can read a single byte like this

```
char c;
read(fd,&c,1);
```

See [`read()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/read.html)

Comment: Ok its working but there is an error *** stack smashing detected ***: ./pro terminated
core dumped.  My function is under edit label in first post

Comment: Check with gdb do back trace and found which line is causing seg fault.

Comment: This code will cause a segmentation fault on my machine. I think you need `char c[1];` since read expects char** not char*.

Comment: @gbtimmon: No standard version of [`read()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/read.html) as defined by POSIX requires a `char **`.

Comment: Quick question: Will this be less efficient than reading to a buffer (char array) in a single `read` call, then iterate through the characters in the buffer? I imagine invoking `read` for each single character is more costly than reading to a buffer...

Comment: @Gangadhar How big should the buffer be? potentially a line could be very long no?

Answer (score 0):

I am reading some data from a file using read. Here I am reading data in a 2d char pointer but the method is the same for the 1d also. Just read character by character and do not worry about the exceptions because the condition in the while loop is handling the exceptions :D

```
  while ( (n = read(fd, buffer,1)) > 0 )
{   

if(buffer[0] == '\n')
{
  r++;
  char**tempData=(char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*r);

  for(int a=0;a<r;a++)
  {
    tempData[a]=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*BUF_SIZE);
    memset(tempData[a],0,BUF_SIZE);
  }

  for(int a=0;a<r-1;a++)
  {
    strcpy(tempData[a],data[a]);
  }

   data=tempData;

   c=0;
}

else
{
  data[r-1][c]=buffer[0];
  c++;
  buffer[1]='\0';
}

   }
```

Answer (score -1):

fgets would work for you. here is very good documentation on this :- 
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/

If you don't want to use fgets, following method will work for you :-

```
int readline(FILE *f, char *buffer, size_t len)
{
   char c; 
   int i;

   memset(buffer, 0, len);

   for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
   {   
      int c = fgetc(f); 

      if (!feof(f)) 
      {   
         if (c == '\r')
            buffer[i] = 0;
         else if (c == '\n')
         {   
            buffer[i] = 0;

            return i+1;
         }   
         else
            buffer[i] = c; 
      }   
      else
      {   
         //fprintf(stderr, "read_line(): recv returned %d\n", c);
         return -1; 
      }   
   }   

   return -1; 
}
```

Comment: The thing is I cant, I have to use read() becouse it is my HW.