# Program gets stuck while trying to read a file using read() system call

Tags: c, linux, file-io, system, system-calls

Here is my code snippet:

```
int fd;
bufsize = 30;
char buf[bufsize];
char cmd[100] = "file.txt";
int newfd = 1;

if (fd = open(cmd,O_RDONLY) >=0){
    puts("wanna read");
    while (read(fd,&bin_buf,bufsize)==1){
        puts("reading");
        write(newfd,&bin_buf,bufsize);
    }
    close(fd);
}
```

So here the program prints `"wanna read"` but never prints `"reading"`. I have also tried opening using nonblock flag, but no use. Can anybody help me? I must use `open()` and `read()` system calls only. Thanks.
Edit: I have made some clarifications in the code. Actually the newfd that I'm writing to is a socket descriptor, but I don't think that is important for this problem because it sticks on the `read` which is before the `write`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19769542/reading-from-file-using-read-function

Comment: That is because it prints "reading" when the number of bytes read is 1, but you requested `bufsize` bytes.

Comment: All you need to do is enable warnings `-Wall` and fix ***all*** of the warnings.

Comment: Please learn how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  There are a lot of issues in the fragment you provide.  It needn't be much larger.  You'd define `bufsize`, `cmd` and include `int main(void) {` before and `return 0; }` after the code shown.  Then you just need 3 headers — not a lot.

Comment: @chqrlie [You missed the error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40051511/program-gets-stuck-while-trying-to-read-a-file-using-read-system-call/40052172#comment67380736_40052172) that I was referring to. And if your compiler didn't warn you about that, then you need a new compiler. That `if` statement is essentially `fd=1;` which points the `fd` at stdout, and that's the reason OP wasn't able to read anything.

Comment: @user3386109: that's great, but why play riddles on newbies instead of helping them?  The extra warning level (excellent advice) would definitely catch the test/assignment mixup, but it would not tell the semantical error on the return value of `read`, unless your compiler is a psychic and I want one like that.

Comment: @chqrlie The most important lesson for any newbie to learn is how to help themselves. And learning how to use a compiler correctly (i.e. read, understand, and fix the warnings that the compiler generates) is lesson number 1. So I'm glad to help a newbie that posts a question like, *"I tried compiling this code, and got these warnings, but I don't understand what the warning means."* But when a newbie pastes incomplete code, with no mention of the numerous warnings, then I don't have much sympathy.

Comment: BTW, the whole premise of your answer is that `bufsize` is not equal to 1, but where in the question do you see that. Answer: nowhere. The question should have been closed for lacking an MCVE.

Comment: @user3386109: I understand your frustration, I personally despise the fact that C compilers still ship with many lifesaving warnings disabled by default! I always turn `-Werror` on, but I'll grant you this one should not be the default.

Comment: @chqrlie Yes, on the lifesaving warnings we agree! As for `-Werror`, it should somehow be required for newbies ;)

Comment: @user3386109: yes! for newbies and for any new project, especially production code.

Comment: My code had two errors which are both addressed in the selected answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `read()` call attempts to read `bufsize` bytes and returns the number of bytes actually read. Unless `bufsize ==`, it is quite unlikely `read()` will return `1`, so the block is almost always skipped and nothing get written.

Also note that `if (fd = open(cmd, O_RDONLY) >= 0)` is incorrect and would set `fd` to `1`, the handle for standard output, if the file exists, causing the `read` to fail as standard input is most likely not opened for reading.

Note that reading with the `read` system call is tricky on some environments, because a return value of `-1` may be restartable.

Here is an improved version:

```
int catenate_file(const char *cmd, int newfd, size_t bufsize) {
    int fd;
    char buf[bufsize];

    if ((fd = open(cmd, O_RDONLY)) >= 0) {
        puts("wanna read");
        ssize_t nc;
        while ((nc = read(fd, buf, bufsize)) != 0) {
            if (nc < 0) {
                if (errno == EINTR)
                    continue;
                else
                    break;
            }
            printf("read %zd bytes\n", nc);
            write(newfd, buf, nc);
        }
        close(fd);
        return 0;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: You've copied the `if (fd = open(cmd, O_RDONLY) >= 0) {` assignment vs comparison precedence bug.  The rest is OK, though I'm not wholly sure about the testing for interrupt stuff as written.  I'd go with the simpler `while ((nc = ...) > 0)` approach.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: OOPS! I missed that one!  Regarding the EINTR stuff, the man page still mentions this: *POSIX allows a read() that is interrupted after reading some data  to  return -1 (with errno set to EINTR) or to return the number of bytes already read.*  I honestly don't know if any signals can interrupt this loop, including ignored ones, but why not play it safe?

Comment: Unless you've set up a signal handler (outside this code), the issue will be moot — the program will be terminated by the interrupt anyway.  The POSIX (2008/2013) specification for [`read()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/read.html) is fairly clear: _If a `read()` is interrupted by a signal before it reads any data, it shall return -1 with errno set to [EINTR].

If a `read()` is interrupted by a signal after it has successfully read some data, it shall return the number of bytes read._  So, the man page you're referring to shouldn't still be accurate.

Answer (score 2):

The first problem is your `if` statement. You forgot to use enough parentheses, so if the `open()` works, the read tries to read from file descriptor 1, aka standard *output*.  If that's your terminal (it probably is) on a Unix box, then that works — surprising though that may be; the program is waiting for you to type something.

Fix: use parentheses!

```
if ((fd = open(cmd, O_RDONLY)) >= 0)
```

The assignment is done before, not after, the comparison.

I observe in passing that you don't show how you set `cmd`, but if you see the 'wanna read' message, it must be OK.  You don't show how `newfd` is initialized; maybe that's `1` too.

You also have the issue with 'what the `read()` call returns'.  You probably need:

```
int fd;
char buf[bufsize];
int newfd = 1;

if ((fd = open(cmd, O_RDONLY)) >= 0)
{
    puts("wanna read");
    int nbytes;   // ssize_t if you prefer
    while ((nbytes = read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf))) > 0)
    {
        puts("reading");
        write(newfd, buf, nbytes);
    }
    close(fd);
}
```

You can demonstrate my primary observation by typing something ('Surprise', or 'Terminal file descriptors are often readable and writable' or something) with your original `if` but my loop body and then writing that somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

`read` returns the number of bytes read from file that can be `bufsize` or less if the remainder of the file that has to be read is shorter than `bufsize`.

In your case most probably `bufsize` is bigger than 1 and the file is bigger than 1 byte so the condition of the while loop is evaluated false, the code is skipped to the point where file is closed.

You should check if there if there are *more bytes to be read*:

```
while( read(fd,&bin_buf,bufsize) > 0 ) {
```