# C - Read from file 1 line at a time without using fgets / getline

Tags: c, file, c99

***Schoolwork — No code please. Pseudo code ok.***

*We are only allowed to use 3 libc functions: `read`, `malloc`, and `free`. However, during the course of school we have implemented and written many of our own versions of libc functions, and those ones we **are** allowed to use. I would list them, but there are about 50 of them, so instead I will be sure to mention which ones I **cannot** use.*

My question...What are the steps I must take to read a line from a file and store that line as a string, without the `\n`? Is anyone able to walk me through the process? Because right now, I don't even know where to begin. I know how to use read, and I would consider myself somewhere between beginner and intermediate skill level with C, but after spending an entire day searching Google, every time this same question has been asked, the accepted answer always involves using `fgets` or `getline`, which we are not allowed to use, for obvious reasons. I have implemented my own versions of many libc functions that could potentially help in this project, but anything that would make this project quick and easy is obviously not allowed.

*Again, please no code, though pseudo code is fine, but I would much prefer it if somebody could help me better understand what I need to 'tell the computer' to do, and from there I should be fine to write the code myself.*

Comment: Read a character at a time, storing them. When you hit \n, stop.

Comment: Duplicate question; answer here answers your question (basically what Phil M said): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19769542/reading-from-file-using-read-function

Comment: Don't be discouraged by the downvotes. Your question is a good one.

Comment: I should have tried to make my post a little bit shorter I suppose, but I guess I was thinking people might just read part of it and think I haven't even tried anything yet, and just want someone to do my project for me. That's why I put twice that I don't want actual code, heh.

Comment: @ElliotTregoning Some people in here are fed up with beginner's questions. Come over to http://reddit.com/r/C_Programming for help not constrained by Stack Overflow's system.

Answer (score 4):

Pseudo-code to read 1 line

```
    buffer to 0, size to 0, size_used to 0
    loop
      read 1 character
      no success? - break loop
      size_used >= size
         make buffer bigger (maybe 2x, at least 1)
         [This involves allocating a new buffer, copy existing data, freeing old buffer]
      add character to buffer
      was character a \n? - break loop

    Nothing read? 
      return NULL
    right-size buffer to size_used+1
    append \0
    return buffer  (calling code needs to eventual free it.)
```

Lots of efficiency improvement are possible.  I suggest starting with a basic version, get functionality correct  and then consider improvements such as

1. Performance: read from the file, maybe 4k bytes at a time.
2. Performance: re-using the returned buffer.
3. Make robust and check for allocation failures.

Comment: In the spirit of consistency with the rest of the standard library (e.g. `strcat`, `sprintf`, `scanf`, etc) I'd advise that `buffer` be allocated by the *caller*, not the *callee*. Also, regarding reading *maybe 4K bytes at a time*, I don't think this is an improvement in performance. I reckon [I proved this in a submission to the *dailyprogrammer* excersize here](https://www.reddit.com/r/dailyprogrammer/comments/2q2zxe/weekly_18_holiday_code_a_time_of_sharing/cnf265o/), but I'd love your feedback...

Comment: @Seb The linked submission does not show results.  The code itself has a  `for()` loop component that takes away from the `fgetc()` v. `fread()` performance compare.  The code's results would be an example, not a proof.  Code works with the `stdin` stream which can have significant performance difference than a _file_ as per this post.  I do not see the  linked code well supporting your doubt.  IAC, any performance improvements that do not change the O() complexity have reduced value to a learner (OP) and is why my answer did not focus on  that in the pseudo code.  Thanks for your insight.

Comment: Then perhaps your list should include the `-O3` and other optimisation-specific switches as they have the ability to drastically alter realistic performance characteristics of an entire project. Please show an example of your 4K-reading optimisation without such a `for` loop... ohh, and on another topic, is an optimisation really an optimisation if it *breaks* functionality? OP wants to read *only up to the next newline* and `ungetc` is *only guaranteed to work once* so you also need to rely upon `fseek`, *which isn't guaranteed to seek meaningfully using offsets for binary files, `stdin`*

Comment: *... or files that are too large*...