# What is causing my C++ cat function to give a "Bad Address" error when opening two or more files?

Tags: c++, unix, file-io

I am attempting to write a function that serves the same purpose as the Linux command 'cat'. The program is successfully opening and reading the first file. However, if two or more files are attempted to be opened and read, then I get a "Bad Address" error message upon trying to open the second file.

````
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <sys/types.h> //open header files
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h> // read header file


using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int fd;
ssize_t nr;




// executable was ran without input files typed afterwards
if(argc == 0) {cout << "No files listed as argument" << endl; exit(1);}






for(int i = 1; i < argc; i = i + 1)
{
fd = open(argv[i], O_RDONLY, 0644); //file opening

char *buffer; // for containing the character string locations of files



if(fd == -1) {perror("File Opening Error"); return 2;} //end if

nr = read(fd, buffer, 100); // not quite sure what to type for the byte count?????

buffer[nr] = '\0';

if(nr == -1) {perror("File REading Error"); return 3;} //end if

cout << buffer << endl;

close(fd);

} //end for
return 0;
}```
````

Comment: `nr = read(fd, buffer, 100);` -- The `buffer` is uninitialized.

Comment: [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19769542/reading-from-file-using-read-function).

Comment: `std::ifstream in(argv[i]); std::cout << in.rdbuf();` is much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

```
char *buffer;
```

This declares a new pointer called `buffer`. It is not initialized to point to anything. The pointer's value is random garbage, at this time. Immediately afterwards:

```
nr = read(fd, buffer, 100);
```

This attempts to read up to 100 bytes into the `buffer`. However since `buffer` is not a valid pointer, and this results in undefined behavior. This is the reason for your program failing.

> The program is successfully opening and reading the first file

Only by random chance. "Undefined behavior" means anything can happen.

```
// not quite sure what to type for the byte count?????
```

That's because there is no valid value by the byte count.

It's simpler to use an actual buffer, instead:

```
char buffer[256];
```

Now you can confidently use a count of 255, leaving room for the trailing `\0` that gets added to the end of the read data.